# Why Deploying Vuetify web always causes caching issues for client?

Tags: vue.js, caching, deployment, vuejs2, vuetify.js

We are deploying a frontend Vuetify. Always when we deploy a new version of the Vuetify code, our client is stuck with the old code unless they do a refresh / clear cache / incognito mode.

How can you force a browser refresh of all cached content from the previous deployment?

[image]
I try to set pwa like that in vue.config.js. But that doesn't help much, I must refresh the page for get updated

Comment: Likely because of default `service-worker` which is `registerServiceWorker.js`? As i see u have workbox setting

Comment: @SC Kim Yeah. How do you know I have a workbox setting? What is the solution to solve this problem?

Comment: it's written there `workboxOptions` in your pwa config.
what i only do is show/hide Refresh button with `on-click=location.reload()` container i made via `updated()` method of `registerServiceWorker.js.` It will remove old-cache and hard Reload on the site once user agreed to click "Refresh" link because every client browser will have versions of service-worker and cache.

Comment: @SC Kim Okay. Can you answer this question with a detail answer? Actually I get this reference :  https://medium.com/js-dojo/vuejs-pwa-cache-busting-8d09edd22a31. But I'm still confused to implement it in the vuetify